# System.Uri does not contain a method named 'new'

Tags: powershell, system

`[System.Uri]::new('http://www.stackoverflow.com')` is failing with error message

> [System.Uri] does not contain a method named 'new'

however I am able to find this method on another box. and runs fine.

How to find if there is difference between System object loaded under PowerShell

Comment: Could you run **$PSVersionTable** and verify the details of two environments?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need Powershell 5 or higher to use the .ctor of a .NET class.
In older versions of Powershell you'll have to use New-Object to do this.

Comment: @wOxxOm : Just tested this on a Server2012R2 machine (PS4) and the new constructor doesn't work there.

Comment: This is interesting. Apparently WPF5 upgrades the entire PS environment so these constructors work in `powershell -version 3` sessions too. IIRC I've used `::new()` successfully in PS4 before I even installed PS5 so it might be .NET framework related. Anyway it doesn't seem a feature of PowerShell 5 per se, because otherwise it shouldn't have worked in `-version 3` sessions (or is it a bug?).

Comment: @wOxxOm `powershell -version 3` on a box with WMF 5 is an illusion :-) Have a look at `$PSVersionTable`